# AppEngine NDB PolyModel getting properties

Tags: python, app-engine-ndb, polymodel

I am having a problem with appengine that I can't seem to figure out:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import polymodel

class Item(polymodel.PolyModel):
      name = ndb.StringProperty()
      type = ndb.StringProperty(choices=["Medical","Food"])
      sub_category_type = ndb.StringProperty()
      sub_category_sub_type = ndb.StringProperty()

class MedicalItem(Item):
      med_sub_type = ndb.StringProperty()
      can_split_item = ndb.BooleanProperty()

class ItemInHouse(ndb.Model):
      item = ndb.StructuredProperty(Item)
      amount_of_item = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

So using the classes above, when I query for all ItemInHouse, and then I try to access those iteminhouse that have a MedicalItem, I am unable to get med_sub_type.  That is:

```
itms = ItemInHouse.query(ItemInHouse.item.type == "Medical").fetch()
for itm in itms:
    self.response.out.write(itm.item.med_sub_type)
```

Throws an error at the itm.item.med_sub_type.  I have even tried: `itm.item._values["med_sub_type"].b_val` but this still throws an AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'med_sub_type'.  I do see in the `class_` property it has `Item` and `MedicalItem` properties, but I am unable to acces it.  Any ideas?

Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear that what you are trying to do may not be possible -- I don't think I had anticipated storing PolyModel instances as StructuredProperty values.  Does that explain what you are seeing?  You may want to file a feature request at the NDB item tracker but I can't promise it will be implemented.

Comment: If there is enough demand, I'd be happy to take a stab at implementing it.

Comment: I think it would be awesome