# Appengine datastore, polymodel, and projection

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a polymodel for all contacts

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import polymodel

class Contact(polymodel.PolyModel):
    telephone = ndb.StructuredProperty(Telephone, repeated=True)
    email = ndb.StructuredProperty(Email, repeated=True)
```

The Telephone and Email model classes have two simple `StringProperty` properties: `type` and `value`.

I have a model `Person` who uses this polymodel:

```
class Person(Contact):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I would like to use projection to reduce the amount of output. So when I query a property of the parent (i.e. polymodel), such as:

```
qry = Person.query(projection=['telephone.value'])
```

everything works. But if I query a property of the `Person` class, (either of)

```
qry = Person.query(projection=['name'])
qry = Person.query(projection=[Person.name])
```

I receive an `InvalidPropertyError: Unknown property name` exception.

Is this a bug of ndb to look into the kind and not the actual class?

Please let me know if there is a way around it (of course one is to not use polymodels). Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Below I present a simpler model (removed `StructuredProperty`) which gives the same issue:

```
class Contact(polymodel.PolyModel):
    telephone = ndb.StringProperty()

class Person(Contact):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
```

This works:

```
qry = Person.query(projection=['telephone'])
```

This does not work:

```
qry = Person.query(projection=['name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems trying to combine StructuredProperty with PolyModel  - see [ndb.StructuredProperty not calling ndb.PolyModel subclass methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870808/ndb-structuredproperty-not-calling-ndb-polymodel-subclass-methods) and [AppEngine NDB PolyModel getting properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419247/appengine-ndb-polymodel-getting-properties)  for instance.

Basically the design of PolyModel and StructuredProperty tend to preclude their combined use.

I know you question is about projection queries but the fundamental problems here will no doubt get in the way of the projection query working.

Comment: I don't think that the combination of PolyModel and StructuredProperty has to do anything with my problem.

Comment: Actually it does.  Read guido's comment about supporting StructuredProperties with PolyModel. NDB  really doesn't support that combination.  If you start looking at how metaclasses are used and also how PolyModel is implemented you will realize that what you are trying to do isn't currently going to work. I suggest you log a bug.